# writing excel from .h5 file: performance

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am saving some data from a .h5 file to an excel file.

I am using openpyxl for that. And, I may not be doing it in a good way but, seems like it is taking too much time for a (quite) small .h5 file.

Do you have any recommendations?

I am currently taking a look at XlsxWriter, but is it really good enought?.

Here is the simple code I am using:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from tables import *
import os
import time

def saveExcel(pyTableName):

    t1 = time.time()

    wb_write = Workbook()
    wsh_write = wb_write.active

    r = 2
    with openFile(pyTableName, 'r') as f:
        tab = f.getNode('/absoluteData')
        for row in tab.iterrows():
            wsh_write.cell(row=r, column=1).value = row['sheet']
            wsh_write.cell(row=r, column=2).value = str(row['IDnum'])+','+str(row['name'])
            wsh_write.cell(row=r, column=3).value = row['line'])
            wsh_write.cell(row=r, column=4).value = row['is_1']
            wsh_write.cell(row=r, column=5).value = row['is_0']
            wsh_write.cell(row=r, column=6).value = row['is_unknown']
            wsh_write.cell(row=r, column=7).value = row['is_ok']
            r+=1

        wb_write.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Results.xlsx'))
        print "SAVED in: ", time.time() - t1
```

And some performance data after running this code:

For a pyTable with 235200 rows x 17 cols it needed 152.976000071 secs

Comment: Do you really need the output to be `.xlsx` or could you use a simple CSV file, which Excel can open just as well?

Comment: I would prefer excel BUT, if I get great benefits with CSV file, then, I could try.

Answer (score 2):

Both openpyxl and xlsxwriter are suitable for the task; xlsxwriter is probably the fastest for just writing files but openpyxl also has a `write_only` mode for this kind of task which is very fast if you also have lxml installed. If you don't have lxml installed then you should see a considerable speedup.

There are several limiting factors:

- converting from the source objects to Python to XML (in this case probably h5, numpy, Python and XML)
- the fact that xlsx doesn't support streaming

In openpyxl we've tried to simplify the API so that you can simply append rows to a cell without worrying too much about coordinates.

Your modified code might look something like this:

```
wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet("Sheet1")
for row in tab.iterrows():
   ws.append({'A':'row['sheet'], 'B': '%s%s' %(row['IDnum'], r(row['name'])}
```

If you do wish to follow the CSV route then it's probably best to use h5dump and define a data source in Excel which might also allow you to choose the columns the way you want.

Comment: im trying this, but getting: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'write_only'` in the line when I do  `wb = Workbook(write_only=True)`, that is weird.... of course previously I have done `from openpyxl import Workbook`

Comment: Sounds like you have an old version of openpyxl. Try `optimized_write=True` instead, though in this case it won't be much faster and you'll be better off with xlsxwriter.

Comment: yes with `optimized_write=True` it works, but not with a great performance though. But, from what you said, I just neeed to install a latest version of `openpyxl` and try with `write_only=True`. It would not be a problem for me.

Comment: Performance will improve if you update **and** install lxml. Otherwise use xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write to CSV and load that into Excel.  Here's the rough code:

```
with openFile(pyTableName, 'r') as f:
    tab = f.getNode('/absoluteData')
    outpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Results.csv')
    np.savetxt(outpath, tab, delimiter=',')
```

That is, you should be able to write the entire CSV using NumPy (or Pandas if you want fancier options, perhaps), without any slow Python loops.

You can also consider Pandas' `to_excel` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is only one thing I don't understand...What do you mean by "slow Python loops"??, my intention is not to write the whole table to excel, just some columns of my intereset, that is why the PyTables loop allows me to solect only the values in the fileds that I am interested in

Comment: I was referring to your Python loop over all rows.  That sort of thing is slow if you have many rows.  The NumPy/Pandas functions implement iteration in C or similar, so iteration can be quite a bit faster.  If you want to select only certain columns, you can slice and dice your data before passing it to `numpy.savetxt`, or you can use the `columns` argument of `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()`.

Comment: CSV is often not a suitable format (it has not type information) and Excel doesn't deal with it very well – you often have to manually provide encoding and type conversion information.

Comment: Well, that is not good then...I didn't know that...I have never worked before with CSV actually...so?? what about XlsxWriter??

Comment: @newPyUser: don't be scared of what Charlie says, give CSV a try and if it doesn't work well, then try Pandas.  Or if you're really scared now because Charlie hates CSV so much that he had to downvote this, go ahead and use Pandas right away.  It'll do what you want.

Comment: I think I should give both Pandas and CSV the opportunity to show me how much they can help me

Comment: xlsxwriter is an excellent library and maybe just what you're looking for in this case because you just need to write files.

Comment: I don't hate CSV. It's lack of type information and encoding support can cause real problems for users. h5 exists for a reason.